# Derivative of $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

> I was reading an article in American Mathematical Monthly and came across this example.It says that derivative of $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ takes on all values in $[-1,1]$ in any interval $(0,\delta)$. I'm not getting this statement completely , I think its derivative involves the term $\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ due which it is able to achieve all values in $[-1,1]$ but for these values of $\cos$ what exactly is happening to other derivative term which is $2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ . Please tell me in details how $[-1,1]$ is being achieved by derivative?

Comment: You can see it visually here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+x%5E2sin%281%2Fx%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [derivative is $ g(x) := 2x sin(1/x) - cos(1/x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate%20x%5E2%20sin%281/x%29) as you noted. Consider the points $x_n := \frac{1}{π n} → 0$. We have

\begin{align}
 g(x_n) = x_n \sin π n - \cos π n = 0 - \cosπ n = 0 + (-1)^{n+1}
\end{align}

So in any interval $(0,\delta)$, we can find $n$ such that $ 0 < x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{π(n+1)} < x_n = \frac{1}{π n} < \delta$. But 
$$\{ g(x_{n+1}) , g(x_{n})\} = \{ -1, 1\}$$

so the derivative achieves the boundary values of $[-1,1]$; by continuity in $[x_{n+1},x_n]$ and the IVT, it achieves all values in $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using the rule that $(uv)' = u'v + v'u$ and the chail rule $(u(v))' = v'u(v)$ yields $$
  \frac{d}{dx} x^2\sin \tfrac{1}{x} = 2x\sin \tfrac{1}{x} + x^2\tfrac{-1}{x^2}\cos \tfrac{1}{x} = 2x\sin \tfrac{1}{x} - \cos \tfrac{1}{x}  = g(x)\text{.}
$$

Now let's restrict ourself to the inverval $(0,\delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\frac{1}{N} < \delta$. Then $x_{-1} = \frac{1}{2\pi N} < \delta$, and $$
  g(x_{-1}) = 2\tfrac{1}{2\pi N}\underbrace{\sin 2\pi N}_{=0} - \underbrace{\cos 2\pi N}_{=1} = 0 - 1 = -1 \text{.}
$$
Similarly, for $x_{1} = \frac{1}{2\pi N + \pi} < \delta$, $$
  g(x_{1}) = 2\tfrac{1}{2\pi N + \pi}\underbrace{\sin (2\pi N + \pi)}_{=0} - \underbrace{\cos (2\pi N + \pi)}_{=-1} = 0 - (-1) = 1 \text{.}
$$
Thus, we know that $g$ takes at least the values $1$ and $-1$ on every interval $(0,\delta)$. But since $g$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ (as the combination of continuous functions) and thus in particular continuous on $(0,\delta)$, we can conclude from the intermediate value theorem that it also takes all values *between* $1$ and $-1$, which proves that $$
  g((0,\delta)) \supset [-1,1] \text{.}
$$
for every $\delta > 0$.